# Batch script to replace lines in a different batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script that has some software versions that looks like this (the numbers can change):

```
set NewVer=123
set NewVerServ=456
set AgeNewVer=789
```

I need to create a different script that, when ran, looks for those specific strings, and replace the numbers with new numbers that I will input in the new script.

I couldn't really get it to work with findstr as it returns mixed results.
I'm sure I'm missing something simple here, can anyone offer any advice?

Comment: Where is this script that you propose to write expecting to find what specific strings?

Comment: These will be two different scripts and they will both be located in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the values in a separate file, then you can rewrite the complete file each time.

```
(
   echo set NewVer=123
   echo set NewVerServ=456
   echo set AgeNewVer=789
) > versions.bat
```

and if you want to use them from another batch file, use:

```
call versions.bat
```

Answer (score 0):

Still no wiser as to which specific strings will be involved, but I'd deduce that this new script is intended to replace the variables `set` in the existing script with new values.

IMHO, the easiest way is to remove those three lines from the existing script (and any other such `set variable` lines as you may consider need to be altered) and use, as your new script,

```
@echo off
setlocal
set NewVer=124
set NewVerServ=457
set AgeNewVer=790
call "oldscript.bat"
```

as the environment inherited by `oldscript.bat` will now contain the required variables set to their new values.